# Goodreads API Get Reviews

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am looking to retrieve the reviews of a certain book from Goodreads API. I am relatively new in APIs.

Here is a link to the API documentation: https://www.goodreads.com/api#book.show

I have created this basic code, and it prints out Success, but no result. Data: Object Document. Here is my code:

```
$.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?format=xml&key=d9xonLKxHDCI5HF1mHjbQ&isbn=9781843589501", function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

What am I missing to be able to display the results?
ap

Comment: You can adjust the format of the data being returned by changing `format=xml` to `format=json`. Then try printing this out in the console instead of alerting it. Also `alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);` will output a string. You should use `console.log("Data: ", data,  "Status: ", status);` to output the object

Comment: I want to use XML, its much harder using JSON, I need to have user ID which I can't seem to find, and understand how to use OAuth. I would prefer to know how to transform the XML data into a readable html format @MattO'Connell

Answer (score 0):

The result being returned is in XML format. You need to have something at your client side to read the XML retrieved. Have a look at the below example https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: but I don't know the tags in the xml object, so its pretty difficult to display it @user3509208

Comment: Have a look at the example link. For e.g   
$title = $xml.find( "title" );-- should return the first value 

 Use something like below $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml", your url
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $.parseXML(xml).find('Table').each(function(index){
            var provider = $(this).find('Provider').text();
            var channel = $(this).find('FeedCommonName').text();
            var hd = $(this).find('FeedIsHD').text();
            $('.box ul').append('<li>'+channel+'</li>');
        });
    }
  });
});

Comment: Also can you post the whole code that you are using. will run in my local and see what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used an external library called: [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)

Here is a code snippet as to make the returned value as you would an object.

```
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;


request(options)
.then(function(data) {
  var xml = data;

  parseString(xml, { trim: true }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) //do something
    else //something else
```

So here, you get the data, turn it into JSON and you can act how you want with it accordingly. Though, realise that you have a callback here!